# OpenCL: how to speed the fps for process image

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, processing, frame-rate

I have started to use OpenCL for the first time and I'm trying to do this example for sobel
edge detection  in this site
http://www.karlosp.net/blog/2012/05/03/opencl-opencv-sobel-edge-detector/
but when run the kernal for gpu number fps is less than 15 and the gpu utilization
is less than 5% how can run all thread for gpu like openmp to make utilization at less 95%

the code

kernal code

_*kernel void sobel(*_global float *A, __global float *R, uint width, uint height)
{

```
int globalIdx = get_global_id(0);
int globalIdy = get_global_id(1);
int index = width * globalIdy + globalIdx;
float a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
float sobelX = 0;
float sobelY = 0;
if(index > width && index < (height*width)-width && (index % width-1) > 0 && (index % width-1) < width-1){
    a = A[index-1-width] * -1.0f;
    b = A[index-0-width] *  0.0f;
    c = A[index+1-width] * +1.0f;
    d = A[index-1] * -2.0f;
    e = A[index-0] *  0.0f;
    f = A[index+1] * +2.0f;
    g = A[index-1+width] * -1.0f;
    h = A[index-0+width] *  0.0f;
    i = A[index+1+width] * +1.0f;
    sobelX = a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i;

    a = A[index-1-width] * -1.0f;
    b = A[index-0-width] * -2.0f;
    c = A[index+1-width] * -1.0f;
    d = A[index-1] * 0.0f;
    e = A[index-0] * 0.0f;
    f = A[index+1] * 0.0f;
    g = A[index-1+width] * +1.0f;
    h = A[index-0+width] * +2.0f;
    i = A[index+1+width] * +1.0f;
    sobelY = a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i;
}


R[index] = sqrt(pow(sobelX,2) + pow(sobelY,2));
```

}

Comment: Are you using clenqueuewrite/read at each iteration? That would decrease performance. If you can do same computation only on gpu, its faster because edge detection is not computationally heavy. It uses mem access mostly. You can optimize the mem access using a shared-mem optimization per thread block if pci-e optimization is not enough. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=602XVhl2QMY this example is many times faster for 256x256 texture resolution when optimized for non-pci-e  access even with particle interactions + deformable mesh calcs. Cl-gl interop is the thing's name. Put some code please.

Comment: Thank you for the answering . can you help me any code i want to make the gpu run 100% like openmp for cpu threads
my actual program read the frame from camera or video and make some process on cpu and then send to gpu to make some process i want canny edge detection and hougth transform
and then return to cpu to complete process. the sobel detection run 15fps for resolution 640*480??  i use clenqueuewrite/read to to read and write from gpu after each frame is this possible to make real time processing???

Comment: Pci-e bandwidth is usually 4-5GB per second. This means 1 billion 32-bit floats per second. 640*480=307200 and multiplying by 4 bytes(rgba) per pixel gives 1228800 bytes per frame which is 1/4000 th of pci-e bandwidth.  You have 15FPS so it is sending probably 16MB per second which is too few. BUT the sending time makes gpu idle. Idling for even a millisecond will give GPU a lower usage percent. If you dont want interop then you can do asynchronous work. First, send 50 to-be-processed frames to gpu. Start the kernel. But in the mean time send and receive new datas while keeping gpu busy.

Comment: Then you can keep the gpu busy with the pre-loaded frames onto gpu-memory. I think its just the reality of you have a high-end gpu I think :)

Comment: You cannot get 100%, even if you optimize it heavily. 5% does not mean the GPU is running at 5%, it mean that the average usage is 5%. If your code runs fast, and the I/O is a bottleneck (as well as the CPU queing data). You will barely go over that level. IE: Very heavy computational tasks usually reach only 50% is the CPU is also bottlenecked.

Comment: from your answer the delay not from kernal code ??? the problem in the data send and receive from gpu is small .

Comment: .if i send 30frame to process and read 30 frame is that faster from send frame after frame.each time send 30 frame but we want to store 30 frame before sending to gpu ??? we have acircular queue to store at least 100 frame before send to gpu . do you have any link help me about that . i hope to see any program process frame for more than 100fps to understand the code

Comment: cvWaitKey() slows down capture/display process
cvWaitKey(x) 
    It waits for x milliseconds for a key press. If a key was pressed during that time, it returns the key's ASCII code. Otherwise, it returns -1.
    It handles any windowing events, such as creating windows with cv::namedWindow(), or showing images with cv::imshow().
    this function wait at least 15ms
any way faster to show my frme gui???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you link to has a few inefficiencies (no particular order):

- The calls to clFinish after every OpenCL call inside the loop are unnecessary.  Firstly, the clEnqueueWriteBuffer and clEnqueueReadBuffer are both using blocking set to CL_TRUE, i.e. they will not return until the write/read has finished (the definition of a blocking function call).
- You convert your unsigned char image into float image before sending it to the GPU.  This is not necessary as the GPU is capable of working with unsigned char and can typecast to float if needed.  Converting to float on the CPU followed by sending to the GPU causes one to send 4x the amount of data (4 bytes per pixel per channel vs. 1 byte).
- You call cvWaitKey(10), pausing for 10 milliseconds to wait for a keypress, hence this code will never exceed 100 frames per second (minor issue).
- The RGB to gray-scale conversion can be done on the GPU, at the expense of sending 3 unsigned chars so there is a trade off there that needs testing.

Your timing approach is also flawed.  Your code measures the time taken to load, process and display a single frame.  Processing consists of both OpenCL and OpenCV components.  You should benchmark each of these separately to determine how long each one takes so that you can determine exactly where your bottleneck lies.

What also just occurred to me is what is the frame-rate of the camera that OpenCV is capturing from?

Comment: Thank you for the answering . i make some change in the code but the utiliztion of gpu also less than 5% and fps is reach 20
1-chang cvWaitKey(10) from 10 to 1 ms 
2-remove clFinish  inside the loop
3-RGB to gray cvtColor(img ,im_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY); if use only this function in side the loop the fps 35 
4-convert your unsigned char image into float image before sending it to the GPU? what change make for that any example

Comment: Do you know any way to optimaize the kernal to use all resource of gpu 
i want to run parallel on gpu the utilization is kess than 5%
i see some kernal use 
get_local_size & get_num_groups can this function help me to make the kernal run faster how can optimize this kernal for 2d image
Thank you

Comment: You would benefit from using shared a.k.a. local memory, but there seem to be other bottlenecks in your code.  How are you measuring GPU usage.  If you are using something like GPU-Z then GPU utilisation sitting at 5% does not mean that 5% of the computing resources are being used, rather it means that the GPU is only busy 5% of the time.  The other 95% it is waiting for work, hence the reason why I say there is a bottleneck elsewhere in your code.

Comment: For example, the RGB-to-grayscale conversion takes 1/35=0.029 seconds.  Your frame-rate of 20fps means that 0.029s of the 0.05s or 57% of your frame time is used by RGB-to-grayscale coversion.  This is already a bottleneck that limits GPU usage to around 40% at best.

Comment: Other thing that comes to mind is that your code did not specify local workgroup sizes, forcing the implementation to guess a good config.  This almost always works badly so you should use a local workgroup size that is a multiple of 32 (works well for AMD and Nvidia GPUs) and pad out your global work size to a multiple of the local work size that is larger than your image dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the answering > i use program "AMD system monitor" for measure GPU usage .when run some example for program "GPU caps viewer" the gpu usage reach 98% when close program return to zero

Comment: the problem for convert unsigned char image into float image is solved

Comment: i see another code for edge detection using opencl and all this code the gpu usage is not more than 10% ??? and the fps reach to 20-25fps . global work size is the size of process image and global div local must be real number and make change for local value but this not change the speed for processing .

Comment: i make change for program remove opencv func cvtColor  and make program convert video from rgb to gray and make some change for code now when run with out opencl only read frame from video and display it rgb only no process the fps is ~40 and less than i dont now why some times reach 50 . then after run opencl rgbtogray the fps reach 30 and gpu utilize reach 15% is ok .

Comment: i have a problem not with opencl but with opencv if i delete opencv function cvWaitKey(1) 1ms that use inside the while loop the process fps change from 30 to 50 fps but no output view in function cv::imshow i will search about that in google .